# chrome.identity.getAuthToken is not working in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to get user token in my extension by using
`chrome.identity.getAuthToken` method.

It worked for some time, at some point it stopped working at all, without any changes in manifest or google cloud console.
Callback method isn't called at all and there is no errors in log. At the same time, `chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo` works just fine.

OAuth 2.0 Client IDs key matches id of my extension on `chrome://extensions/` page and manifest contains key and proper scopes. How can I make it work?

Manifest

```
  "oauth2": {
        "client_id": "***.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "scopes":[
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "identity",
        "identity.email"
    ]
```

Example code

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, token => {
        alert('callback executed')
});
```

Comment: I was able to get the same configuration as yours to work correctly.
Is there anything output to the DevTools console?

For a bogus client_id the following is printed:
popup.html:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: OAuth2 request failed: Service responded with error: 'bad client id: {0}'

For a bogus key the following is printed:
popup.html:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: OAuth2 request failed: Service responded with error: 'bad client id: 955607574923-l8t8ejk3js6nts2kj9drcjrasjeeujf7.apps.googleusercontent.com'

Comment: @NorioYamamoto Thanks for you reply! I have error `OAuth2 request failed: Service responded with error: 'bad client id`  only when I use invalid client_id on purpose (or when I change key in google cloud console to invalid one). When everything is correct I can't see any output at all

Comment: Is it the same if you create a new client_id and try using that?

Comment: @NorioYamamoto, yep, already tried with several client ids. I thought it may be caused by the key in client_id, but `chrome.identity.getRedirectURL("oauth2")` returns url with the same extension id I used for client_id

Comment: Your extension was working correctly before, right?
My final idea would be to recreate the key in the Chrome Developer Dashboard.